# Accessing subclasses from the parent class

Tags: c#, class, subclass

For a lot of the applications that I build, I use a custom class that holds a number of commonly used methods.

Over the course of time, this library has become quite extensive and now I'm trying  to clean up that library and to add subclasses for every category such as general, debug, logging and settings.

Currently my class looks like this:

```
public class General
{
    public Form frmMain;

    public void updateText(Control ctrl, string content)
    {
        if (ctrl != null && (ctrl is Label || ctrl is TextBox))
        {
            if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ctrl.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    ctrl.Text = content;
                }));
            }
            else ctrl.Text = content;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is convert it like this:

```
public class Library
{
    public class General
    {
        public Form frmMain;
        public void updateText(Control ctrl, string content)
        {
            if (ctrl != null && (ctrl is Label || ctrl is TextBox))
            {
                if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    ctrl.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        ctrl.Text = content;
                    }));
                }
                else ctrl.Text = content; 
            }
        }
    }

    public class Settings
    {
        public Form frmMain;
        public void someMethod() { }
    } 
}
```

In the implementation I want to reference the class Library for example:

```
Tools.Library library = new Tools.Library();
```

But I don't really want to implement new variables for every subclass. Ideally I would like to access the different methods from within the Library class.
For example:

```
Tools.Library library = new Tools.Library();
library.General.updateText(lblTest, "test");
library.Settings.someMethod();
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Make the General and Settings class static (and of course all the methods inside these classes)

Comment: From the code you posted, it would look like you could just make these static classes and methods. Your constructor isn't taking any arguments and the `frmMain` is not referenced in the methods. In general, I find that if I have a reusable utility method then it most likely can be made static and live in a static class.

Comment: This is terrible design... but if you can't achieve some separation of concerns than I guess the solutions above are decent.

Comment: Have you tried inheritance? `Class General extends Library` That way the General class gets all the methods of the Library class. It’s not common to declare a class within another class as you do in your code

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for the support ;-) I'm always open for suggestions, how would you handle this?

Comment: Using actual subclasses (as opposed to nested classes) is a start; next would be getting all those UI concerns out so your classes are actually testable and reusable. In an ideal world you would be following an MV* pattern but that's difficult in WinForms. WPF would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides setting all of the nested classes as static (if that works for you needs, do it as that is a better option), you can implement your nested class "general" in the constructor of your main class "library". This is a little weird though.

Also I think it's important to note that this is not a "SubClass" which is a totally different thing. These are "Nested class". You can get some very wrong advice on Google if you are searching up "subclass" and trying to apply those suggestions to your "nested class" idea here.

```
namespace Tools
{
    public class Library
    {
        public General general;

        public Library
        {
             general = New General();
        }

        public class General
        {

            public Form frmMain;


            public void updateText(Control ctrl, string content)
            {
                if (ctrl != null && (ctrl is Label || ctrl is TextBox))
                {
                    if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        ctrl.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                        {
                            ctrl.Text = content;
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctrl.Text = content;
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        public class Settings
        {

            public Form frmMain;


            public void someMethod()
            {

            }


        }

}
```

Then you can reference and it's methods without initializing the nested class (as it's already initialized in the constructor of the main class).

```
Tools.Library library = new Tools.Library();
library.general.updateText(...);
```

Comment: Still, I think that, if those classes are really a generic all-purpose bunch of methods then it is probably better the _static_ approach and avoid all those  constructors

Comment: Thanks JNevill for your answer. In terms of design, would this be the right approach to achieve some structure in commonly used methods or would you use another approach?

Comment: I don't feel super confident in answering that. I've definitely used nested classes like this to model a complex object. A parent object that has it's own methods and properties (Like a Car has a color and can accelerate) that has a child class where that child class would never be implemented outside of the Parent, and yet is distint from the parent in that it has it's own properties and classes (Like an Engine which has a number of cylinders and can increase or decrease the amount of gas it intakes). The engine is then nested in the Car class and is implemented with the Car's implementation.

Comment: One of the nice things you can do here is in the constructor of `General` you can take, as a parameter, the parent class. `public General(Library parent)` and have `parent` as a property of `General` setting it in the constructor `this.parent = parent;`. Then when you implement `general` in your `Library` constructor you can do `general = New General(this);`. Now `General` gains knowledge about the instance of the Class in which it's nested. In the Car/Engine example the implemented `engine` would know things about it's `Car` then.

Comment: *but... that might not make sense in your situation as this seems like class nesting for the sake of code organization. I mean.. if that's the case then it might just make sense to make the whole thing static since it's unlikely that you are going to implement multiple instances of `Library` or if you do, then probably not multiple instances `General`.. you know? Like this feels like you are tossing in commonly used functions into a class structure. It's hard to say though since I don't know what "Library" and "General" mean in this context.

Comment: I will probably use multiple instances of Library because I might have two different forms that will each use the LoggingClass of Library to log errors or statuses.

Comment: And could it be you are missing () in the above example where you declare public Library to initialize the general = new General()?